# Error date time string must match iso 8601 format in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have datetime string containing value 12/20/2023 04:57:00.

I need to create file using copy activity from this string like 20231220_045700.parquets when I am using formatDateTime function to get date and time I am getting error the datetime string must match iso 8601 format.

Is there any other way to do this

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way to do this

Use the below expression in the copy activity filename to achieve your requirement. Here, `date` variable contains the input string `12/20/2023 04:57:00`.

```
@concat(formatDateTime(variables('date'),'yyyyMMdd_HHmmss'),'.parquet')
```

[image]

**Result:**

[image]